# Using events to save storage costs

Tags: solidity, scalability

Is it beneficial to use events to store data when possible. I'd like to avoid storing excess data, as the data is only a reference for the outside world and has no functionality within that contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can save gas by using events instead of permanent storage. If the data is not needed in the contract itself, this makes a lot of sense.

See https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e for a description of this use case.